# Finding previously visited website by the client asp.net

Tags: asp.net, http

How do I find the previously visited website with ASP.NET?

In other words, what is the alternative for

`getenv('HTTP_REFERER')`

of PHP in asp.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx

It would be Request.UrlReferrer

However you need to check for null because if the request came from say, a company network, which stripped off the referrer header, you wont receive this information.

Answer (score 2):

[Request.UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx)